# Attribute Error where collections has no attribute called "MutableMapping" in firebase_admin module

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database

when I try to import firebase_admin, it throws this error:

```
class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

I searched and found that 'collections.MutableMapping' has changed into 'collections.abc.MutableMapping', but there is nothing wrong with the module. All usages are correct, I don't know the problem.
I am running python 3.10